# parsley.js is not working in my Django form validation

Tags: javascript, html, django, parsley.js

This code in Django does not show any validation errors. Am I missing any syntax or tag?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/side_file.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/parsley.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/side_file.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/parsley.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form data-parsley-validate method="POST">
       {{form}}
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you loading `parsley.js` twice?

Comment: Do you have `jquery.js` linked on the page?

Comment: Errors in the console should make things clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/side_file.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script> # add jquery
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/parsley.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form data-parsley-validate method="POST">
       {{form}}
    </form>
</body>
```